# How to support Hindi Text In Brightscript Roku channel

Tags: roku, brightscript

In my channel, we have some text coming in the Hindi language. So when this type of text come cross-type of mark comes in the channel in that text. In Roku, the English language supports perfectly.

So is there any option to support other languages in Roku

Answer (score 0):

Language characters are not necessarily platform-dependent, in most cases they are font-dependent, so you just need to use the right font.

A great choice is the Google Noto font, this font covers pretty much all languages.
https://www.google.com/get/noto/

The [documentation](https://developer.roku.com/docs/references/scenegraph/typographic-nodes/font.md) explains very well how to use custom fonts.